# Can i avail rebate on Home loan interest without sale deed and registration

Tags: income-tax, mortgage, india

I have booked a flat in June 2011 and taken loan from bank. I am paying EMI since August 2013. Physical possession of flat given to me in November 2014 but sale deed not given to me by builder till date and flat not registered in my name. Can i avail rebate on Home loan interest.

Comment: More than tax you would need to worry as you are paying for a house that is not yours. I am also surprised that the Bank extended the loan to you.

Answer (score 1):

As the flat is not registered in your name, you cannot avail rebate on the Interest Paid. Rebate can only be claimed on self owned property.